# How to efficiently manage docker storage drive in Centos 7

Tags: docker, centos7, docker-volume

I would like to clarify some questions with docker experts regarding usage of docker container in Centos 7. Please find the details about the docker,

```
$ docker version
Client:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:55:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      1.13.0
 API version:  1.25 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.3
 Git commit:   49bf474
 Built:        Tue Jan 17 09:55:28 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

I am using centos 7 and the version is `CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)`

I am currently having few issues related to managing the docker storage drive, so i am listing everything over here,

1. If i am correct, Docker uses /var/lib/docker by default for saving all the information about images and container. My disk space in root directory is less than 20 gb and as soon as the container starts to process for few mins, the disk space filled up to 100%. So i have mounted a disk partition /dev/sdb. I have done lot search in google and everyone is suggested to configure the **docker-storage-setup**, but with the latest version of docker 1.13 i was not able to find the **docker-storage-setup** in order to make the docker use /dev/sdb for storing all the information about images and container. Can anyone explain how to make docker use the mounted disk partition /dev/sdb instead for /var/lib ?

   2. I am quite not familiar about docker volumes and would like to know whether mounting volume while starting container will solve the above mentioned issue or still docker will save all its information inside /var/lib ?

**EDIT :**

```
$ docker info

Containers: 3
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 26
Server Version: 1.13.0
Storage Driver: overlay
 Backing Filesystem: xfs
 Supports d_type: false
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins:
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 03e5862ec0d8d3b3f750e19fca3ee367e13c090e
runc version: 2f7393a47307a16f8cee44a37b262e8b81021e3e
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 seccomp
  Profile: default
Kernel Version: 3.10.0-514.6.1.el7.x86_64
Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 15.51 GiB
Name: docker
ID: WYAF:SDYL:LVAU:OKDP:O6K2:ZLG6:RMIB:SET4:SWGN:6TBR:ST6K:4W55
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

$ df -h

```
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/centos-root   14G   14G  647M  96% /
devtmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7.8G   25M  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1                497M  216M  281M  44% /boot
/dev/sdb                 296G   65M  281G   1% /mnt
overlay                   14G   14G  647M  96% /var/lib/docker/overlay/dfa0c4e618c259bf046b454b27a7963fb31b9d4e95cc745ed28696b0791e3166/merged
shm                       64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/6e978cecc472322ef984cdb73117ed0243eb88c30d37c93827084bec88dcf15a/shm
overlay                   14G   14G  647M  96% /var/lib/docker/overlay/9cdd3dc933f93febccaa7e06ba2f86023d3dd655614be5d9e636ab75f21873f4/merged
shm                       64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/ed44174945e331246f622e42a6ea646504075a91e4922168d895ed295cd24109/shm
overlay                   14G   14G  647M  96% /var/lib/docker/overlay/c2bc2c73f0f3b0e717f8ea134aad8554ebb6b77c2dcfd85e8035a645bf75d074/merged
shm                       64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/26fd8e67dc7da80f6047add17aaddd7f67f763966d4a6b65d08680ac41774a28/shm
tmpfs                    1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
```

$ docker system df

```
TYPE                TOTAL               ACTIVE              SIZE                RECLAIMABLE
Images              4                   3                   4.441 GB            -1.644e+09 B (-37%)
Containers          3                   3                   6.867 GB            0 B (0%)
Local Volumes       0                   0                   0 B                 0 B
```

Comment: Please add the output of `docker info` (also the output of `docker system df` can be helpful)

Comment: added output of docker info and docker system df

Comment: what did you end up doing here. Looking for best setup for docker storage on CentOS 7.4